# Activate hard-blocked WiFi adapter

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, drivers, blocking

I am having the problem that I have an old laptop I want to make a headless Debian install on. However, this is one of those laptops with a physical switch. But it's not that easy. This isn't an on/off-switch, but a sliding switch that snaps back into its original position, that used to open a small window where I could enable and disable WiFi. Also it has a F-Key mapped to WiFi, but that isn't working either now. That was using Windows XP. In the meantime I had already wiped the disk and installed Debian, and then this issue appeared, so I can't go back. I also tried the original drivers, but also those didn't work out.

Dos any one of you have any idea how to turn on this WiFi module? Also the OS isN't of any importance, I just want to get that adapter reenabled.

P.S.: I have enabled the wireless adapter in the boot menu.

Comment: Does `rfkill` show the card as soft blocked or hard blocked or not at all? Does `evemu-record` report the switch producing any events? What's the card model?

Comment: Well, it was reported as hard-blocked under rfkill, that's why I wrote this in the first place. To answer your second question: I will see. I reinstalled windows xp with the hope of getting the driver again, but it didn't work out. let me just boot it up with a live cd. But at least under XP, there appeared that hourglass just for the blink of an eye.

Comment: At least under LMDE 4 (Linux Mint based on Debian), evemu-record didn't show the switch